# Passing parameter in POST method without hidden field asp.net

Tags: html, webforms

I have a post method and in which, I want to pass some parameter like student_id.
I am able to do that by using hidden field but I don't want to use hidden field.
some thing like this:

```
<form id="form1" action="post" src="https://mydomain.com?student_id=value">
```

Please note that I am trying to hide the information from the URL.
I know html very well so don't worry about syntax.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps if you told us why you think the hidden field is not the proper solution we could formulate other ideas. Btw, `?student_id=value` is mixing POST and GET (pretty pointless).

Comment: You are trying to hide information from the URL by putting it in the URL? Say What?

Answer (score 0):

The three choices as I see them are:

1. Put the data in a hidden field -- perhaps stored in the viewstate if you don't want it easily available via the page source.
2. Put the data in the url -- or a proxy of the data, say an encrypted slug that decrypts to the actual id if you don't want the id to actually be visible.
3. Put the data in a cookie, perhaps encrypted.

I'd need to know more about your requirements before I could make a recommendation.  You say that you want to avoid the first two, but its not clear to me whether you could use them if the value was encrypted or proxied (say using a database id instead of the student id). Typically, I proxy it using an artificial database id (autogenerated integer) and put it directly in the URL, but I would be using ASP.NET MVC instead of webforms, too.

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about showing the client-side a piece of sensitive data, the answer is to avoid sending it altogether.

Store the value on your server either in a data store or cache and pass a key to the value in the form. So for example:

```
<form id="form1" action="post" src="https://mydomain.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="student-cache-key" value="23154546">
```

And then when the form is posted, you would look up `23154546` in your table or cache to retrieve the value... (psuedo-code)

```
int studentId = cache.Get(post['student-cache-key']);
// studentId now equals 5, or null etc
```

Whatever mechanism you use, you would have to check the value existed in the store and handle the case where it isn't.